# CakePHP read cookie in all controllers

Tags: cakephp, cookies

Today I have a question about cakePHP cookies.
How to tell cake php to remember cookies in all application controllers?

I want to do simple agreements accept.

For example i have 2 controllers. Agreement and Infopages. User must accept agreements to see infopages and other stuff on my app.

This is my agreement controller (only example):

```
class AgreementController extends AppController {
    var $components = array('Cookie'); 

    public function acceptAgreement(){
        $this->Cookie->write('agreements', 'accepted');
    }
}
```

This is my pages controller (only example):

```
class InfopagesController extends AppController {
public function showPage(){
    $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('agreements');
    if($cookie=="accepted"){
        /* CODE TO SHOW PAGE */
    }
    else{
        /* REDIRECT TO AGREEMENTS */
    }
}
```

I want to redirect all controllers of my application to agreement controller if cookie is empty..
I try to doo that but cakephp remember cookie only in actions of agreement controllers.

Definition of my cookie component(in agreement controller)

```
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Cookie->name = 'regulamin';
  $this->Cookie->time =  3600;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Add the check to you AppController::beforeFilter()

```
   $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('agreements');
   if ($cookie != "accepted" && (get_class($this) != 'YOUR-AGREEMENTS-CONTROLLER' && $this->action != 'AGREEMENTS-ACTION')) {
        /* REDIRECT TO AGREEMENTS */
   }
```

Make sure you do not redirect to the agreements page if you access it, if you don't do that you'll end up with a redirect loop. Change the condition from my example to whatever you need to check if the user is trying to access the agreements page.

Also make sure you call parent::beforeFilter() in your Controllers beforeFilter() call. If you do not know about calling parent methods or how to use this correctly have a read about phps OOP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

Use Sessions. Cakephp site has some good info on reading and writing. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html

Also place your session check in the app_controller.php in a beforeFilter() callback to forward everything there if the session is empty. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

Comment: Yeah i know it but id like to do it on cookies, because browser remember it for a long time...

Comment: It sounds like people have a login, if true, you should really just save it to the persons profile, read it on login and save it to session. The cookie way has no security.

Comment: No, its only must be a link to the action, and this action set a cookie. If cookie is not exists, user see a page witch terms and conditions, and must click accept. 

If i use session, and user will close webbrowser and open it again, he must again accept terms and conditions, and this is not good

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in InfopagesController doesn't work because you forgot to load the Cookie component, as you have correctly done in AgreementController.

After this, in your AppController::beforeFilter() check:

1) what is the controller;

2) if the controller is not equal "AgreementController", then check if user has the cookie.

You need to check if is not equal "AgreementController" otherwise you create an infinite redirect.